# Is no sql database a good solution for a small application?

Tags: jdbc, nosql, rdbms

I am developing an internal web application that needs a back end. The data stored is not really RDBMS type. Currently it is in XML document fashion that the application parses (XQuery) to display html tables and other type of fields.
It is likely that I will have a few more different types of XML documents and CSV(comma separated values) coming up. Given the scenario, I can always back the data up with a mySQL database, breaking the process that generates XML or CSV to insert straight in to database.

Is no-sql database a good choice in this scenario? or mySQL is still better? I do not see any need for clustering/high availability/distributed processing scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "better".

I think the choice should be made based on how relational (MySQL) or document-based (NoSQL) your data is.

A good way to know is to analyze typical use cases.   Better yet, write two prototypes and measure.

Comment: "better" based on learning curve involved in setting up and programming to no-sql.

Comment: find somebody smart enough to figure it out.  The effect on the application is far more long-lasting than a short term learning curve issue.

Comment: What'd you learn in the last nine months that made this the accepted answer?